# Returning an empty smart pointer

Tags: c++

I have a class that looks like this,

```
class A
{
   std::shared_ptr<Type> ret;
public:
   A()
   {
     ret=std::shared_ptr<Type>(new Type);
   }
   std::shared_ptr<Type> GetTypeA(){return ret;}
   A (const A&a)
   {
     ....
     ret=a.ret;
   }
};

class Type
{
   A aa;   
public:
   Type(A*a):aa(*a){}

};
```

Somewhere in the client code, I call the method GetTypeA like this

```
void func(A*pA)
{
...
   std::shared_ptr<Type> spT=pA->GetTypeA();
...
}
```

Debugging shows me that `spT=empty` after the call. But inside `pA`, `ret` value is NOT empty.

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where's your copy constructor for `class A` ?

Comment: @Jagannath I updated my post. Please reread it.

Comment: How do you want to default construct `Type`? Seeing as `A` creates a new `Type` and `Type` holds an `A` by value, it seems like this is a recursive dependency.

Comment: Yes, that's the intent, I'd like them to be inter-dependent. Other languages automatically resolve this. So I wonder how this is done in C or C++

Comment: @DavidCattor you solve it yourself in C++ :)

Comment: Yes I am trying to do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice some mistakes in your code :

```
A()
{
   ret=std::shared_ptr<Type>(new Type);
}
```

"new Type" means you call default constructor for Type (Type::Type()), and you didn't write it in your sample. Try "new Type(*this)" to use your own constructor.
But to do this you need to change your Type class to:

```
class Type
{
    A* aa;                       // Use a pointer

public:
    Type::Type(A&a) :aa(&a){}    // Use references
};
```

The problem is it's not resolving the "recursive aspect", depend your needs, I would use a static reference to A in the Type class...